# Arm Mali T-624 gpu arithmetic pipeline depth kernel

Tags: arm, kernel, opencl, hardware, mali

I am doing a research on an Arm Mali T-624 board and i want to discover how many stages does the gpu arithmetic pipeline has and i am doing the running the following kernel

```
 __kernel void arithmetic_pipeline_depth(__global  int * list)
{
   for(int j=1000000;j!=0;j--){}
}
```

And i am running this kernel from 1 to 512 workgroups while i keep the number of work-items stable to number 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgyFG.jpg)

So the results for this expirement is that the arithmetic pipeline is about 38 stages long

Do you think it is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by **pipeline**?  Workgroups are like CPUs, but GPUs can often do several results in parallel with SIMD type processes.  The other use of **pipeline** refers to the number of steps pre-fetch, dispatch, execute, floating point, memory load/store, etc.  It seems like you mean **pipeline** as the number of OpenCL workgroups?  Or what is the maximum computation to do at once?  This is often related to memory depending on the algorithm and GPU structure.  I think most ARM GPUs have a unified memory structure, which makes it simpler.

Comment: I'd expect the compiler to optimize out the loop, as it's totally redundant, so I don't think you're measuring what you think you are ...